# Eclipse Template Default Value with Dot

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-templates

I want to have a default value in a String with a dot. I can't save my template when I put in the dot, though. Is it possible to get the dot into the string?

```
System.out.println("${related.string}");
```

So I want to have `related.string` as one string, which means when I get in with the cursor it should behave as one, so if I type something, it should vanish all.

I get the error: `Template has incomplete variables. Type '$$' to enter the dollar character.` in the UI.

Comment: I use this to indicate the "path" through my paket structure. By default i want it to have i18n.strings for my internationalization template. But if I have a different path, I want to completely erase the whole string as soon as I type.

Comment: Because I use `i18n.strings` as default and I need the dot, I currently use `"${i18n}.${strings}"`. It works, but if I don't need the dot, I need to erase it myself. Though, If the filename is still strings but the path is different this one is shorter.

Comment: I get you now. I can't figure out a way to do this - it doesn't appear to support escaping of any kind that I can see.